# I have to edit only one property in a JS object, can I spread only a portion of a said object when passing it as an argument to a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a JavaScript object with the following structure:

```js
{
    id: 0,
    content: "English Class",
    date: "Dec 24th at 7:30pm",
    completed: false,
}
```

I also have a function `const editTask(id, content)` that updates the `content` property in the aforementioned object:

```js
const editTask = (id, content) => {
    setTasks(tasks.map((task) =>
      task.id === id ? { id: task.id, content: content, date: task.date, completed: task.completed } : task));
  }
```

Is there a way in which I can avoid passing *all* the object properties to only upgrade the `content` property as well as just spreading the rest of the object?

Comment: `{ ...task, content }`?

Comment: You said it yourself in the question, just spread. How can you know the word "spread" and Google but not know the spread syntax ?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. I was under the impression that I could only use spread with the "whole", complete object.

Comment: @Touffy I do know the syntax, I just had a small doubt about it.

Comment: `...task` _does_ spread the whole complete object, then part of it gets overwritten using shorthand notation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh, I see. Thank you for that clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common pattern is to combine the spread syntax with manually setting some properties:

```
const editTask = (id, content) => {
    setTasks(tasks.map((task) =>
      task.id === id ? { ...task, content } : task));
  }
```

In the above example, the spread syntax sets all the properties of `task`, and the next line overrides the property `content` to the new value. It's important that the spread is *before* the `content`. If it were after, then the new value would be overridden by the spread.